# Возможно ли скомпилировать node.js файл в .exe?

Tags: node.js, компиляция, exe, discord-api

Написал бота для дискорда с помощью discord.js. Нужен мне этот бот редко, так что запускаю со своего компьютера, без всяких хостингов. Появилась необходимость скинуть бота знакомому, что бы тот тоже мог его запускать. Не будет же он ради это устанавливать себе node.js на компьютер. Вот мне бы и хотелось скинуть ему просто exe файл. В крайнем случае папку с файлами, в которой будет exe файл. Приложение просто консольное. Более того, нет никакого взаимодействия с консолью, она просто отображает информацию, которой можно и не пользоваться.

Comment: а почему бы не поискать в google? найти там pkg, electron. поэкспериментировать.

Comment: можно создать бат фаил и в нем прописать старт имя фаила

Comment: @user324714 абсолютно не то, что нужно было. Это можно использовать только на тех компьютерах, на которых установлен node.js. Я использовал pkg для решения своей проблемы.